# How to retrieve data for radio button value and select the radio button from sqlite in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-studio, radio-button

```js
   private void collect_data() {

        //----- collection & validation for is_required
        String the_choice = "";
        at_leaset_one_checked = false;
        for (RadioButton rb : allRb) {
            if (rb.isChecked()) {
                at_leaset_one_checked = true;
                the_choice = rb.getText().toString();
            }
        }

        if (the_choice.length() > 0) {
            Answers.getInstance().put_answer(textview_q_title.getText().toString(), the_choice);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Your ques and asn is:" +textview_q_title.getText() +the_choice, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


      
        }
        q_data = (Question) getArguments().getSerializable("data");
        ques_type = (q_data.getQuestionType());
        ques = textview_q_title.getText().toString();
        ans = the_choice;
        DbHelper db = new DbHelper(getActivity());
        if(db.QuesdescExist(ques))
        {

            db.updatedata(ques,ans);
        }
        else {
            db.insertdata(,ques_type ,ques, ans, date, status);
        }


    }


    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        mContext = getActivity();
        q_data = (Question) getArguments().getSerializable("data");

        textview_q_title.setText(q_data.getQuestionTitle());


        List<String> qq_data = q_data.getChoices();
        if (q_data.getRandomChoices()) {
            Collections.shuffle(qq_data);
        }

        for (String choice : qq_data) {
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(mContext);
            rb.setText(Html.fromHtml(choice));
            rb.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
            rb.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            radioGroup.addView(rb);
            allRb.add(rb);

            rb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    collect_data();
                }
            });
        }
```

I am storing the data of Question in database as the radio button is clicked as answer but when i go to another activity I want that going back to question that question should have its answered clicked . Please if anyone can help me with this.

Thank You in advance

Comment: put some code , what have you done

Comment: List<String> qq_data = q_data.getChoices();
        if (q_data.getRandomChoices()) {
            Collections.shuffle(qq_data);
        }// database code here........for (String choice : qq_data) {
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton(mContext);
            rb.setText(Html.fromHtml(choice));
            rb.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
            rb.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            radioGroup.addView(rb);
            allRb.add(rb)

Comment: you can edit post by edit option. please put your code there.

Answer (score -1):

check this

```
 import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.RadioButton;
    import android.widget.RadioGroup;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

      private RadioGroup radioGroup;
      private RadioButton radioButton;
      private Button btnDisplay;

      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        addListenerOnButton();

      }

      public void addListenerOnButton() {

        radioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio);
        btnDisplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDisplay);

        btnDisplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                    // get selected radio button from radioGroup
                int selectedId = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

                // find the radiobutton by returned id
                radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

                Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,
                    radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });

      }
    }
```

xml

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radio"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioMale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_male" 
            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioFemale"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/radio_female" />

    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: This is not what i am asking . sorry.

Comment: I already have stored the value in database now i want it to retrieve the data and want to show it in activity by selecting the radio button programmatically according to the value stored earlier.